# NSFetchedResultsController only updating with deletion of objects but not with insertions

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an NSFetchedResultsController that basically updates a UITableView with a list of objects updated in a background NSOperation instantiated/updated off an API call from a Web service. I have implemented the various NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods (e.g. `controllerWillChangeContent`, `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath`, etc.) with code from this site: http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller

The problem is a row is never inserted in the UITableView when an object matching the predicate is inserted. However, when I do delete an object that is already presented in the table view, its corresponding row disappears correctly.

The below is the code for instantiating the NSFetchedResultsController:

```
 - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // is a nearby category of objects - check to see if passed in
    if (self.nearbyCat == nil) return nil;

    // Creates a new NSManagedObjectContext
    NSManagedObjectContext *moContext = [[Utils getUtils] newManagedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *nearbyObjDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:ENTITY_NAME_OBJECT inManagedObjectContext:moContext];
    [req setEntity:nearbyObjDesc];

    // predicate key path is passed into the view controller is an ivar - fetchKeyPath
    NSString *predKeyPath = self.fetchKeyPath;
    NSString *catName = [self.nearbyCat valueForKey:kCategoryNameKey];

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K like %@)", 
                         predKeyPath, catName];
    [req setPredicate:pred];
    [predKeyPath release];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:kObjectScoreKey ascending:NO];
    [req setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    [req setFetchBatchSize:20];

    _cacheName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"NearbyObjectsFor%@", catName];

    // In case there are new objects created because of change in location, 
    // we delete from the cache first, keeping the cache fresh.
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:_cacheName];

    NSFetchedResultsController *myFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:req managedObjectContext:moContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:_cacheName];
    [moContext release];

    self.fetchedResultsController = myFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    [sort release];
    [req release];
    [myFetchedResultsController release];

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

I use the recommended method of registering for NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification and then performing the mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification: on the main thread in the method mergeContextChanges below:

```
- (void)mergeContextChanges:(NSNotification *)note 
{ 
    if(note.object && self.fetchedResultsController)
    {

        SEL selector = @selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:);
        [[self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext] performSelectorOnMainThread:selector withObject:note waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}
```

Has anyone faced a similar problem before?

Comment: You state: "The problem is ... when I **delete** an object..." So is your problem occurring with deletion or insertion?

Comment: Sorry should have been clearer. The problem is when I insert the table view does not update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the insertion has been executed and saved successfully, call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: On the simulator, the call to `reloadData` after deletion has the effect of clearing the whole UITableView. On insertion, after the save, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS in `controller:didChangObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:`. I was under the impression that using an NSFetchedResultsController you wouldn't have to call reloadData.

Comment: I normally set the `fetchedResultsController` to `nil` first so it is re-instatiated in the getter. See if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've used something similar to your method but I was getting a few errors, possibly because of the way my class was written. So I adapted it and posted the solution below. Since you inspired me, I'll mark your solution as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried multiple ways and decided to opt for a NSFetchedResultsController pair solution. I originally wanted the nice animation effects when a row is inserted but that seems like a no-go now so I settled just for reloading the whole table.

Basically, I listen for a notification that is posted when a successful query is returned from a web service. I then switch to another NSFetchedResultsController instance, perform the fetch and call the table update method. I see some animation, but it's for the whole table rather than just for the relevant rows; I see it as a compromise for having data retrieval happen in the background.

Thanks for the help.

Some pseudocode for the notification handling method:

```
method handleServiceRetrievalSuccess
    Get current fetched results controller, frcA
    Release frcA
    Instantiate new fetched results controller, frcB
    Set frcB as current fetched results controller
    frcB->performFetch
    Reload table view
```